# How can i disable navigation active

Tags: css

[navigation image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb8d2.png)

how can i disable the green color there whenever i click in gallery page?

Home

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="Gallery.aspx">Gallery<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <div class="pc-nav">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="col-sm-3 col-md-push-3">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header" style="text-align:left">Company Trips</li>
                                    <li style="text-align:left; visibility:hidden;"><a href="CompanyTrip.aspx#2016-Vietnam"> 2016 - Vietnam</a></li>
                                    <li style="text-align:left;"><a href="CompanyTrip.aspx#2015-Guilin"> 2015 - Guilin</a></li>     
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

CSS here

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="col-sm-3 col-md-push-3">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header" style="text-align:left">Company Trips</li>
                                        <li style="text-align:left;"><a href="CompanyTrip.aspx#2016-Vietnam"> 2016 - Vietnam</a></li>
                                        <li style="text-align:left;"><a href="CompanyTrip.aspx#2015-Guilin"> 2015 - Guilin</a></li>                                        
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

Comment: Where's the CSS? That's all HTML

Comment: .navbar-white .current {
background-color: #00b200; 
}

Comment: <li class="current"><a href="default.aspx">Home</a></li>

Comment: What color do you want it to be?

Comment: And clicking on what would trigger this change?

Comment: i was mean i want one sub-menu with background color. because now parent and child navigation bar is colored

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `current` class indicates the column you have selected. Given the markup you provided in the comments, you can rewrite the rule like this to remove the background color:

```
.current {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

If you do not have access to the original code but wish to override it, you can supersede the background-color property like this:

```
.current {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

But in the end, if you don't wish there to be any special background color for the `current` column, you can just delete the entire block of code.

**EDIT**

Based on your feedback, I assume you want to highlight the names of the countries in the list but not the first item of the list.  In that case, you can target them like this:

```
ul.dropdown-menu ul li:not(.dropdown-header) {
  background-color: #00b200;
}
```

Comment: i was mean i want one sub-menu with background color. because now parent and child navigation bar is colored